# JS "for in" error IE7/8

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using jquery validation plugin for some forms in my sites. But one of the form's validation doesn't work ONLY on IE7 and 8. But other form using the same validation script works. I tried to debug and found out that the problem is in showErrors part, show object doesn't support error when I loop through errorMap using "for in" JS. Any idea how to get that fixed?

Here is the HTML I've got

```
<form name="donate" id="form1" action="https://www.xxxx.xxx.xx/api/help" method="POST" target="_top">     
            <input type="hidden" name="face" id="faceinput" style="clear: both; margin:0; padding:0;">
            <input type="hidden" name="image" id="imageinput" style="clear: both; margin:0; padding:0;">
            <h3>Thank you for helping! </h3>
            <h4>Please fill out the following details.</h4>     
            <label>Name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" class="required" />
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <label>Email: </label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="required email" />
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <label>Amount: </label>
            <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" class="required number minStrict" /><input type="button" id="submitBtn" value="Donate" />
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div id="error" style="display:none;">
                Oops! The minimum amount to donate is $6. Don't wish to donate? Please click on the close button on the top right hand corner instead.
            </div>
        </form>
```

JavaScript

```
    $('#form1').validate({
                onkeyup: false,
                focusInvalid: false,
                rules : {
                    amount : {
                        required    : true,
                        number      : true,
                        minStrict   : 5
                    }
                },
                messages : {
                    fullname: "Please fill out your name",
                    email: {required:"Please fill out your email address",email:"Invalid email address"},
                    amount: {required:"Please fill out amount to donate",number:"Invalid amount",minStrict:"Minimum amount is 6$"}
                },
                showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
                    alert('here');

                    for(error in errorMap){
                        alert(error);
                        /*if(error=="fullname" || error=="email" || error=="amount"){
                            //if(errorMap[error]=='Minimum amount is 6$') {
                                //$('div#error').show();
                            //}
                            //else {
                                $(':text[name='+error+']').val(errorMap[error]).addClass('error');//append err msg in all text field and hightlight
                                $('div#error').hide();
                            }
                        }*/
                    }
                }
            });

$('#submitBtn').click(function(){
            if( $("#form1").valid()){
                alert('here');
                $('div#error').hide();
                $('#form1').submit();
            }
        });
```

Error

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method 
validate.js, line 26 character 5

Fixed by just adding var error...

for(var error in errorMap){ //

Comment: This wouldn't be the problem, but you might want to use `for(var error in errorMap){` so that `error` isn't exposed globally

Comment: So does it never alert the `error`?

Comment: Is the js code you posted in the "validate.js" file? Or "validate.js" is another seperated file?

Comment: validate.js is same file i have that script in

Comment: oh wow thanks Ian i think its works by adding var error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but using

```
for(var error in errorMap){
```

Seems to fix your problem as posted in the comments...

Comment: Seriously curious as to why using `error` in the global scope would cause problems? What if you define `var error;` in the global scope then use `for(error in errorMap) {`.

Comment: I'm assuming here that `error` is defined as part of the jQuery functionality within this scope. Hence the error being returned `Object doesn't support this property or method`. That explains it!

Comment: @Lavabeams Well, I think the point is that if you don't use `var` when declaring a variable, it creates it in the global scope. So since loops technically declare a local variable (in whatever way), not using `var` does this. So you really wouldn't have to declare `error` in the global scope, just in the same scope as the `for` loop should be fine. And if `error` even was defined in this scope by jQuery, the loop should overwrite it. But jQuery can't magically populate the scope without passing parameters (which the OP defined as `errorMap` and `errorList`...no `errors`)

Comment: So I am, as well, curious as to why it's the problem. Unless you can correct whatever I'm misunderstanding

Comment: @Lavabeams But at the same time, there could be a variable `errors` declared in the same scope as the original `$('#form1').validate({` , but again, I would think that the loop just overwrites the value. I don't know.......